# Delete whole anchor tag in contenteditable div on one keypress

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="edit" contenteditable>
            This is <a href="#">link</a> that is editable.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is a very simple text editor where you can put in links (they would get turned into html via JS) but when you hit backspace in the back or delete in front of them, I want it to disappear at once (not deleting anchor text letter by letter).

How would one go about it? My steps with Javascript would be sth like this:

1. When pressing Backspace key, detect if `</a>` is before the cursor, if so run regex on the section before cursor, pick a first match and replace it with blank space.
2. The opposite, detect if Delete key is pressed, check if `<a ... >` is in front of it and remove it as well.

I'm just not quite sure how to put this in code and also if I can run regex and have it recognize the text in contenteditable area. I'd like to avoid any heavy external libraries because the text editor will not really do much more besides this.

If anybody wants to fork [my Codepen here it is](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdbadP).
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Using jQuery's `.keydown()` on a `contenteditable` element works, at least on Chrome. Not sure about browser compatibility. The keydown handler receives the event object: `e.which` is the key that was pressed. Handle the event, check for the key's ID, then verify the content of your element.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clean way to solve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="edit" contenteditable>
            This is <a href="#" contenteditable="false">link</a> that is editable.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding a contenteditable="false" will register the anchor as a whole and not letter by letter.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the method down to pass in the string and re-assign the value of the contenteditable section, here's an example of how to structure the regex.

```js
var textblock = document.getElementById('edit')

function testContent(deletetype) { // deletetype == "delete" || "backspace"
  var txt = textblock.innerHTML.toString().trim(),
    rgxstring = "<a[^<]+<\\/a>",
    rgx

  if (deletetype == "delete") {
    rgxstring = "^" + rgxstring
  } else {
    rgxstring += "$"
  }

  rgx = new RegExp(rgxstring, "i")

  console.log(txt, txt.match(rgx))

  textblock.innerHTML = txt.replace(rgx, "")
}

testContent("backspace")
```

```html
<div id="edit" contenteditable>
  This is <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your regex is working like a charm for one anchor tag but it fail if there is more than one anchor tag and user want to remove the anchor tag one not latest anchor tag

Comment: Ah, yeah this code is just a regex proof of concept example based on the full content of the div, you still need to add your own logic that detects the cursor position and only tests against the string starting or ending from that point.